# how to create a table with javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this php function, which I want to convert to javascript function, but I don't know how to create a table in javascript.

I guess I have to have a container (DIV) to insert the table into with javascript.

Here is the php function simplified: (it counts height and width and repeats a 1px shadow to create a drop-shadow effect)

```
function drpShadow($pic_url){

    $pic_display="<table border='0' style='display:inline;' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td width='4px' height='$height'><img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_top_left_corner_4x4.jpg'><br>";
    for ($i=0; $i<($height-4); $i++){
        $pic_display.="<img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_left_4x1.jpg'><br>";
    }
    $pic_display.="</td><td width='$width' height='$height'><img src='../temp_images/$pic_url'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' height='4px' width='($width+4)'><img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_left_bottom_corner_4x4.jpg'>";
    for ($i=0; $i<=($width-6); $i++){
        $pic_display.="<img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_bottom_1x4.jpg'>";
    }
    $pic_display.="<img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_right_bottom_corner_4x4.jpg'></td></tr></table>";
    return $pic_display;
}
```

Please guide me, or even better, give me some code :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd see if you can do it with CSS, however your JavaScript might look something like the following, I have not verified this.

```
function drpShadow(pic_url, width, height) {
    var i;
    var pic_display
        = "<table border='0' style='display:inline;' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td width='4px' height='" + height + "'><img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_top_left_corner_4x4.jpg'><br />";

    for (i = 0; i < (height - 4); i++) {
        pic_display += "<img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_left_4x1.jpg'><br />";
    }

    pic_display +=
        "</td><td width='" + width +
              "' height='" + height +
              "'><img src='../temp_images/" + pic_url + "'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' height='4px' width='" + (width + 4) + "'><img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_left_bottom_corner_4x4.jpg'>";

    for (i = 0; i <= (width - 6); i++) {
        pic_display += "<img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_bottom_1x4.jpg'>";
    }

    pic_display
       += "<img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_right_bottom_corner_4x4.jpg'></td></tr></table>";
    return pic_display;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<html><head>
<script language =javascript >
function dynamictable()
{
var table1=document.createElement("table");
table1.id="tab1";
table1.border=1;
var tmpRow = null;
var tmpCell = null;
tmpRow=table1.insertRow();
tmpCell=tmpRow.insertCell();
tmpCell.innerText = "Row1 Cell1";
tmpCell=tmpRow.insertCell();
tmpCell.innerText = "Row1 Cell2";
tmpRow=table1.insertRow();
tmpCell=tmpRow.insertCell();
tmpCell.innerText = "Row2 Cell1";
tmpCell=tmpRow.insertCell();
tmpCell.innerText = "Row2 Cell2";
document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(table1);

}

</script></head>
<body onload="dynamictable()">
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just prep the HTML string (just like you're doing in PHP) and assign it as the `innerHTML` attribute of whatever parent element you want -- a `div` is fine, of course, but it could be most anything, really.  Your PHP code doesn't insert that HTML anywhere in particular -- you can write a Javascript function that returns the HTML string, and it will look very similar -- in either case, just having the function does nothing, you'll need to call it and **put** its resulting HTML **some**where!-)

Answer (score 0):

In the case you want to do more with your javascript table later, you might want to look into some kind of plugin for some javascript framework. One example of such a plugin would be [http://www.datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net/) ...

Answer (score 0):

It's almost JavaScript.

Change the ".=" string concatenation to "+=".

The other thing you'll have to change: PHP can see the $variables inside the strings, but JavaScript can't.

Answer (score 0):

```
function drpShadow(pic_url)
{    
    pic_display="<table border='0' style='display:inline;' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td width='4px' height='" + height + "'><img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_top_left_corner_4x4.jpg'><br>";
    for (i=0; i<(height-4); i++){
        pic_display+="<img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_left_4x1.jpg'><br>";
    }
    pic_display+="</td><td width='" + width + "' height='" + height + "'><img src='../temp_images/" + pic_url + "'></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' height='4px' width='" + (width + 4) + "'><img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_left_bottom_corner_4x4.jpg'>";
    for (i=0; i<=(width-6); i++){
        pic_display+="<img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_bottom_1x4.jpg'>";
    }
    pic_display+="<img src='/SV/Graphics/drop_shadow_right_bottom_corner_4x4.jpg'></td></tr></table>";
    return pic_display;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider as well a javascript template engine such as [PURE](http://beebole.com/pure/version2)

This allows you to separate cleanly the data and the HTML.